USB camera bandwidth limit verification
I am working on a project involving 2 sets of stereo camera pairs and I am trying to sync them all together. All cameras are USB3.0 cameras. I have developed the sync board that generates PWM at the desired frequency to trigger each camera hardware trigger pins. Due to some limitation of the project, I have to use USB cameras and can't use other protocol but I have ensured that all camera are connected through USB3.0 port (my setup only have one USB3.0 root controller as well) through a USB3.0 hub
The desired operating specs are one stereo pair (see3Cam_20CUG)with 1600x1300 resolution with 8-bit (Y8) greyscale image at 60fps and the other stereo pair (thermal) with 640x512 resolution with 16-bit (Y16) images at 60fps. While the calculated expected bandwidth is around 2.6 Gbit/s which is below the rated 5 Gbit/s of USB3.0 but I assume that there are some overheads so I digress there. I went a try different combination of resolution and framerate settings for both camera to see what works.
A combination of resolution and rates I found that works is for see3Cam_20CUG 1280x720 res with 8-bit greyscale at 60fps and for thermal 640x512 res with 16-bit greyscale at 60fps which is expected to use 1.5Gbit/s. I would like to retain the max resolution of the see3Cam_20CUG at 1600x1300 so reducing the framerate to around 30 fps also works. However, due to the nature of thermal, reducing the rate to 30fps degrades the quality so thermal needs to be triggered at 60fps.
My next approach now is to have the camera pairs triggered but PWM signal with different frequencies but still synced through their rising edges and being dividers of each others (60fps for thermal and 20fps for see3Cam_20CUG). This becomes see3Cam_20CUG at 1600x1300 at 8-bit at 20fps and thermal at 640x512 at 16-bit at 60fps. However, testing this configuration still results in USB bandwidth issue although it is expected to only need 1.3Gbit/s. I would like to ask if my assumption of it being a bandwidth issue correct and if so, why does the configuration with 60fps for both which uses 1.5Gbit/s works while the 60fps+20fps configuration which expected to use 1.3Gbit/s not work? Is there extra overhead for high resolution that does not scale with the actual value for the image resolution?

The limitation might be in the PC processing the signals, as well as in USB 3.0. Also note that free-running video cameras may have frame-rate differing from 60 fps -- e.g.,  59.94 fps might be used (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate). Since your cameras are externally synced, that sould not be an issue, though.
